# Ensure that ASP.NET 3.5 Framework is installed on Windows Server 2003 64-bit

Tags: iis, windows-server-2003, 32bit-64bit

I'm developing in 32-bit XP and deploying to a Win2k3 64-bit server set to run in 32-bit mode.

How do I install 3.5 framework components on the Win2k3 server in this scenario? I see that there are new charting controls and an SP1 for ASP.NET 3.5

How do I get these on the server that is running in 32-bit mode in IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the x64 package for .Net 3.5 will install **both** the 64 bit and 32 bit frameworks.

With ASP.Net, you will need to do the following:

1. Set IIS to run in 32 bit mode:

   cscript %SYSTEMDRIVE%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1
2. Set the appropriate .Net version/bitness for your application:

   %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

This [KB article (KB894435)](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/894435) has all the details you need.